# How to send HTTP request from file

Tags: python, curl, request, python-requests, netcat

I have a .txt file with a http request (Header + Body). How can I send the HTTP request present in the file using Python or a tool such as curl or netcat (from command line)?

I would like to "repeat" the request included in the file using python/command-line. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to send requests to a certain url, then there's a library called requests. if i got this wrong then maybe you meant how to send a custom packet? in that case there's a useful library called scapy

```
import requests

class spammer():
    def __init__(self,nameoffile):
        self.urls = {}
        self.nameoffile = nameoffile
        self.hamspam(-1)
        self.results()

        print(' call hamspam with a variable indicating the amount of spam')

    def hamspam(self, times_spammed):

        if times_spammed < 0:
            with open(f'{self.nameoffile}.txt','r')as urls:
                lines = urls.readlines()

            for element in lines:
                resp = requests.get(element)
                self.urls[element] = {"resp":resp.status_code,"reason":resp.reason}
        else:
            for key in self.urls.keys():
                _ = requests.get(key)
                print(f'spamming url {k}')


    def results(self):
        for k,v in self.urls.items():
            print(f"for url: {k} the response was {self.urls[k]['resp']}, for reason {self.urls[k]['reason']}")
            

Spammer = spammer('nya')
```

this is a small script ive made to do this with python, ive renamed variables to be self explanatory, hope it helps :)